# Check if trap is set in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, signals, bash-trap

Is there a way to check what `trap`s have been set (in the current session or script) in Bash?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to get a list of the signals that have a `trap` assigned to them, but if that's not possible I can just check each signal individually.

Comment: I am amazed I could not find any info on this from Googling and searching other StackOverflow questions, so I won't be surprised if there's a duplicate somwhere I just didn't find.

Comment: have you tried typing `trap` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Obviously not! Well, now I feel dumb.

Comment: @Cyrus Ah. I'd tried `man trap`, but that didn't work.

Comment: `trap` is a bash bultin command. See: `help`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**.

You can either see all traps, or traps for a specific signal:

```
$ trap            # show all traps for all signals
$ trap -p SIGINT  # only show traps for SIGINT
$ trap -p EXIT    # only show traps for EXIT
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's define a function as follows:

```
$ function f
> {
> echo trapped
> }
```

Let's set the trap to that function assigned to SIGINT

```
$ trap f SIGINT
```

Let's list set traps:

```
$ trap
trap -- 'f' SIGINT
trap -- '' SIGTSTP
trap -- '' SIGTTIN
trap -- '' SIGTTOU
```